# Print on the same line, step after step

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've developed a Python script that performs several tasks in a row (mainly connecting to servers and retrieving information).

There are many steps, and for each of them I would like to display a dot, so that the user knows there is something going on.

At the end of each step, I do:

```
print('.', end='')
```

And in the final step, I write:

```
print('Done!')
```

It works, except nothing is displayed until the final print is executed, so it kind of defeats its original purpose :)

Basically, nothing is displayed on the screen, and at the very last moment, this pops up:

```
.......Done!
```

How can I force Python to print on the same line step after step?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, `stdout` is line buffered, meaning the buffer won't be flushed until you write a newline.

Flush the buffer explicitly each time you print a `'.'`:

```
print('.', end='', flush=True)
```

The `flush` keyword was added in Python 3.3; for older versions, use `sys.stdout.flush()`.

From the [`print()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> Whether output is buffered is usually determined by *file*, but if the *flush* keyword argument is true, the stream is forcibly flushed.

and from the [`sys.stdout` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) (the default value for the *file* argument of the `print()` function):

> When interactive, standard streams are line-buffered. Otherwise, they are block-buffered like regular text files.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the 3.0 documentation and didn't see the Flush option. In [the latest version[(https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) it's here :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using print, you can write directly to stdout, (unbuffered):

```
import sys
import time

for i in range (10):
    time.sleep (0.5)
    sys.stdout.write('.')
print 'Done!'
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the buffered/unbuffered thing.

Answer (score 0):

for python 2.7.3 you can left a trailing comma which tells the idle to not insert a line after the statement is printed for example

```
print "hello",
print "world"
```

would return

```
>>> hello world
```